# Slide dynamic jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to use jQuery to create an dynamic loop in an for loop.
For some reason when clicking the link that page is opened in an new window instead of sliding down.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.moreDetails').click(function() {
$(this).parent().next().toggle('fast');
});
</script>

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo '<tr onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);" onclick="setHighlighted(this);">
              <td colspan="11"> <a href="includes/js/ajax_details_adres.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class="moreDetails">(details)</a><div class="details" id="details'.$row['id'].'">More details</div> </td>
          </tr>';
}
```

Comment: you need to wrap your functions inside $(document).ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the contents of `includes/js/ajax_details_adres.php?id='.$row['id'].` to be loaded in a div on click of a link, try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.moreDetails').click(function() {
       var rowID = this.id;
       $(this).siblings(".details").load("includes/js/ajax_details_adres.php?id="+rowID);
       $(this).parent().next().toggle('fast');
    });
});
</script>

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo '<tr onMouseOver="addHighlight(this);" onMouseOut="removeHighlight(this);" onclick="setHighlighted(this);">
              <td colspan="11"> <a href="#" class="moreDetails" id="'.$row['id'].'">(details)</a><div class="details" id="details'.$row['id'].'">More details</div> </td>
          </tr>';
}
```

What you want to be doing on click is getting the contents of the URL you have set as the target of your link and loading it into the current page, correct?  So you need to use ajax to load the content into your existing page.  This is done via [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  The code above may not capture exactly what you want to do, but it should get you started.

Comment: @justkt Nothing seems to happen although it seems what I need.

Comment: @Muiter - as I said at the end of my answer, I don't think this code gets all the way to what you want.  I think we're missing some important details from your question - what *exactly* is supposed to happen on link click.  Where *exactly* does the new content go?  What is the point of the loop?  I've also edited my answer slightly, realizing I left off wrapping the click handler binding in a ready() function callback.

Comment: @justkt This loop is part of an address list. When clicking the link I need to have additional information should be loaded loaded below the TD. Thanks for trying te help me out.

Comment: @Muiter - do you have Firebug?  With code similar to this do you see the call being executed on click?

Comment: @justkt Nothing happens in Firebug

Comment: @Muiter - tested it out in [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARr8n/).  Will change my answer based on my findings.  Since I do not have access to your code the URL returning a 404.

Comment: @justkt, Great, getting THE result now. Is there an way to move the link to click into the onclick in my TR?

Comment: @Muiter - you should actually try to avoid using onclicks in HTML as part of good [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).  Instead continue to bind using the jQuery click handler, but you can attach it to `$("tr")` (if you have other `<tr>` tags on the page, give those rows a class and do `$("tr.detailsRow")`.

Comment: I'm an bit confuesed. I have tried  $('tr.detailsRow').click(function() with <tr class="moreDetails" id="'.$row['id'].'"</tr>

Comment: Do your `<tr>` tags have a class of `detailsRow`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.moreDetails').click(function(ev) {
    $(this).parent().next().toggle('fast');
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

preventDefault prevents the a from opening its href. So it only executes the javascript click handler.

Comment: did you include the ev parameter in the function? maybe you missed that. -> function(ev){